# Error in : `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on Shiny vizualization with 2 inputs.

Dataset:

```
est_popai <- data.frame(concat = c("A_1","B_1","C_1","A_2","B_2","C_2","A_1","B_1","C_1","A_2","B_2","C_2","A_1","B_1","C_1","A_2","B_2","C_2","A_1","B_1","C_1","A_2","B_2","C_2"),
                  variables  = c("quantity","quantity","quantity","quantity","quantity","quantity","price","price","price","price","price","price","quality","quality","quality","quality","quality","quality","size","size","size","size","size","size"),
                   values = round(runif(24, 5.0, 7.5),2)
                 )
```

UI:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel(
    h1("Combinacao de atributos")
  ),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("xcol"," Variavel X", unique(est_popai$variable),
                selected = 'price'),
    selectInput("ycol"," Variavel y", unique(est_popai$variable),
                selected = 'size')
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot1") 
  )
)
```

Server:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  selectData <- reactive  ({
    
    est_popai[est_popai$variable == input$xcol | est_popai$variable == input$ycol,] %>%
      unique() %>%
      spread(variable,value)  
  })
  
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = selectData, aes(x = input$xcol, y = input$ycol)) +
      geom_point()
  })
  
  
}
```

Run:

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I run the whole code i got this error message:

> Warning: Error in : `data` must be a data frame, or other object
> coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class
> reactiveExpr/reactive   [No stack trace available]

I've tried to add `as.data.frame()` function with no success. Someone could help me to solve this erro, I've been searching a while.

Comment: Try changing the `data` argument in the ggplot function to `data=selectData()`

Comment: I got other erro: Warning: Error in eval_tidy: object 'variable' not found
  [No stack trace available] @JohnPaul

Comment: Try aes_string instead of aes

Comment: Please, close the topic once solved.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the questioner has answered their own question, without marking it as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Copy-pasted from OP.

Please see below the corrected script. The errors were in 3 parts:

> 1- I forgot to add () in  data ggplot function  `data = selectData()`
>
> 2- The objects had different names, I forgot the letter `s` in
> `variable` and `value` objects
>
> 3- `aes()` is supposed to be `aes_string()` in `ggplot` function

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel(
    h1("Combinacao de atributos")
  ),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("xcol"," Variavel X", unique(est_popai$variables),
                selected = 'price'),
    selectInput("ycol"," Variavel y", unique(est_popai$variables),
                selected = 'size')
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot1") 
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  selectData <- reactive  ({
    
    est_popai[est_popai$variables == input$xcol | est_popai$variables == input$ycol,] %>%
      unique() %>%
      spread(variables,values)  
  })
  
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = selectData(), aes_string(x = input$xcol, y = input$ycol)) +
      geom_point()
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```